# WebWorks for the Blackberry development

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I have an idea of developing for Blackbery using WebWorks,But from which OS does the WebWorks will be suitable.I know that WebWorks is suited for 5.0 OS and above.

But in 5.0 itself when developing using java development,i was not able to show google maps using javascript in web page (browser field) in 5.0 ,but it shows route map in 6.0 but hangs while loading,in 7.0 Os,it is Ok,

So While i face similar sort of issues while developing using WebWorks.

I am not a web developer,I dont have teh idea over this Web development stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's available for OS 5 and above
developing in WebWorks can fully support javascript.
but it may show some lags and bugs at OS 5 , but it wrok fine with OS 6 and 7

Answer (score 0):

Most of the features are not supported in os 5 and 6 so from os 7 the webworks is suaitable for development.
e.g. Videoplayer and InAppPurchase is not supported in os 5 and 6.